# React dispatch action updates state after second click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have got my own `AuthContext` and one of its method is `signUp`
Here is the reducer

```
const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'signIn':
            return {errorMessage: '', token: action.payload.token}
        case 'facebookSignIn':
            return {errorMessage: '', token: action.payload.token}
        case 'clear_error_message':
            return {...state, errorMessage: ''}
        case 'signOut':
            return {token: null, errorMessage: ''}
        case 'add_error':
            return {...state, errorMessage: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

 const signUp = dispatch => async ({name, email, password}) => {
        try {
            const facebookId = null, age = null, roles = ['ROLE_USER']
            const response = await request.post(
                '/auth/register',
                {facebookId, name, age, email, password, roles}
            )
    
            await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', response.data.accessToken)
            await SecureStore.setItemAsync('user_email', email)
    
            dispatch({type: 'signIn', payload: response.data.accessToken})
            navigate('Search')
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: 'SIGN_UP_ERROR'})
        }
    }

// ...other methods

export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
    authReducer,
    {signIn, signOut, signUp, clearErrorMessage, tryLocalSignIn, facebookSignIn},
    {token: null, errorMessage: '', user: {id: -1, email: ''}}
)
```

And here is my method to signing up in different screen

```
const {state, signUp, clearErrorMessage} = useContext(AuthContext)
const onRegisterPressed = data => {
        signUp({name: data.name, password: data.password, email: data.email})
.then(() => console.log('INSIDE ', state))
        };
```

here is the result of `console.log('INSIDE', state)`

first click:

```
INSIDE   Object {
  "errorMessage": "",
  "token": null,
  "user": Object {
    "email": "",
    "id": -1,
  },
}
```

second click:

```
INSIDE   Object {
  "errorMessage": "SIGN_UP_ERROR",
  "token": null,
  "user": Object {
    "email": "",
    "id": -1,
  },
}
```

createDataContext file

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react'

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
    const Context = React.createContext()

    const Provider = ({children}) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue)

        const boundActions = {}
        for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)
        }

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }

    return {Context, Provider}
}
```

and the problem is that the state is updated after the second click on register button. First click returns the empty `errorMessage` while it should returns `SIGN_UP_ERROR`. The same problem was with `signIn` action. Generally, the state is updated after second click.

How to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're not passing `dispatch` to `signUp` function with the call. I suppose you're using `useReducer`, so instead of passing dispatch as an argument you can use dispatch function from there, but I'm not sure how it's implemented so I can't help you with that.

Comment: I am not using `useReducer`. I have just added some more code to my post. Hope its enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for more insight. As I can see you're checking context state value in the `promise.then`, but I think it's not gonna be there at this point of time, because `promise.then` is triggered just after the call. At this point of time state is not updated. On second click it's already updated, that's why It's working. I'm not sure what do you want to achieve here, but I would suggest rather not use promise.then if you are managing state in the context. I would use state from the context. I think this should work.

```
const { state, signUp, clearErrorMessage } = useContext(AuthContext);
const onRegisterPressed = (data) => {
  signUp({ name: data.name, password: data.password, email: data.email });
};
console.log(state);
```

If you want to have value in the promise you will need to return it in the implementation of `signUp` function.

```
const signUp = (dispatch) => async ({ name, email, password }) => {
  try {
    const facebookId = null,
      age = null,
      roles = ["ROLE_USER"];
    const response = await request.post("/auth/register", {
      facebookId,
      name,
      age,
      email,
      password,
      roles
    });

    await SecureStore.setItemAsync("token", response.data.accessToken);
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync("user_email", email);

    dispatch({ type: "signIn", payload: response.data.accessToken });
    navigate("Search");
    return { type: "signIn", payload: response.data.accessToken };
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: "add_error", payload: "SIGN_UP_ERROR" });
    return { type: "add_error", payload: "SIGN_UP_ERROR" };
  }
};
```

Then in the call

```
const { state, signUp, clearErrorMessage } = useContext(AuthContext);
const onRegisterPressed = (data) => {
  signUp({
    name: data.name,
    password: data.password,
    email: data.email
  }).then((promiseState) => console.log("INSIDE ", promiseState));
};
```